# Return single value from Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm using the census_api gem to fetch population data for a given county.

This is my code:

```
<%= foo = @census.where({ fields: 'P0030002', level: 'COUNTY:037', within: 'STATE:06' }) %>
```

which returns in the view:

```
[{"P0030002"=>"4936599", "name"=>"Los Angeles County", "state"=>"06", "county"=>"037"}]
```

What do I need to return only the value of the first hash pair? (In this example, "4936599")

Comment: do you know what the keys will be? ex: that `P0030002` is the first key-value pair?

Comment: Yes, the P0030002 is the first key-value pair. (It's the Census' field name).

@sawa's answer below worked, although if anyone can shed some light on HOW, I'd appreciate it. (I'm quite new to Ruby.)

Comment: @sawa is setting the query result to a variable `a`. The result is an array that contains a hash with multiple key/value pairs. `a[0]` accesses the first (and only) element of the array, which as I said is a hash. To access the value of a key `k` of any hash `h`, you call h[k] and the value is returned.

For more info read up on the Ruby Docs:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [{"P0030002"=>"4936599", "name"=>"Los Angeles County", "state"=>"06", "county"=>"037"}] 
a[0]["P0030002"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_of_hashes = [{"P0030002"=>"4936599", "name"=>"Los Angeles County", "state"=>"06", "county"=>"037"}]

array_of_hashes.first.values.first # => "4936599"
```

We start by accessing the first value in the array (only a single hash here, so we get the full hash. Then we get an array of only the values (the 2nd part in each pair) and take the first one.